# Save a GeoJson with ipyleaflet / Access to Markers List

Tags: python, geojson, folium

The Draw plugin, in folium, can "export" all the objects (including markers), made with the plugin, to a GeoJson. I intend to get all the markers information on the map (coordinates) in order to save them or process them. I can save an HTML an look for them inside of it, but it's very messy.

Is there a way to "export" (like folium) or save the markers to a GeoJson or to have access to the list of the markers on the map?
thx

Answer (score 0):

This is a way (kindly explained by davidbrochart) with an example at https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/master/examples/DrawControl.ipynb

```
def handle_draw(target, action, geo_json):
    print(action)
    print(geo_json)
```